# select multiple key and values from a JSON output using JQ

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a JSON data like below

```
[
  {
    "id": 4449282,
    "iid": 6316,
    "project_id": 1234,
    "sha": "abcdefg",
    "ref": "test_branch",
    "status": "running",
    "source": "web",
    "created_at": "2023-09-25T05:55:20.788Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-09-25T05:55:23.481Z",
    "web_url": "https://example.gitlab.com"
  }
]
```

I want the output to be filtered only with select key and values. The filtered output I need is

```
[
  {
    "iid": 6316,
    "project_id": 1234,
    "ref": "test_branch",
    "status": "running",
    "source": "web",
    "created_at": "2023-09-25T05:55:20.788Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-09-25T05:55:23.481Z",
    "web_url": "https://example.gitlab.com"
  }
]
```

I tried with `jq 'with_entries` and `jq select` , but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to provide what to keep, you can use the `pick` filter if you have jq 1.7:

```bash
map(pick(
  .iid, .project_id, .ref, .status, .source,
  .created_at, .updated_at, .web_url
))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rfUCPj0K-uc)

If you don't have jq 1.7, you can define it by copying it over from the [source](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L259-L263):

```bash
def pick(pathexps):
  . as $in | reduce path(pathexps) as $a (null;
      setpath($a; $in|getpath($a))
  );

map(pick(…))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KH2CYZ-Si_8)

If you rather want to provide what to delete, use `del` instead:

```bash
map(del(.id, .sha))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/k0374yav7kI)

---

As you've tried using `with_entries` and `select`, here's how you could achieve the desired result using these filters:

Selecting what to keep:

```bash
map(with_entries(select(.key | IN(
  "iid", "project_id", "ref", "status", "source",
  "created_at", "updated_at", "web_url"
))))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fA7fED-m0Fh)

Selecting what not to keep:

```bash
map(with_entries(select(.key | IN("id", "sha") | not)))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/w75-AZOcmGY)

---

All of the above output:

```json
[
  {
    "iid": 6316,
    "project_id": 1234,
    "ref": "test_branch",
    "status": "running",
    "source": "web",
    "created_at": "2023-09-25T05:55:20.788Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-09-25T05:55:23.481Z",
    "web_url": "https://example.gitlab.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```bash
$ jq '[.[] | {iid: .iid, project_id: .project_id, ref: .ref, status: .status, source: .source, created_at: .created_at, updated_at: .updated_at, web_url: .web_url}]' file
[
  {
    "iid": 6316,
    "project_id": 1234,
    "ref": "test_branch",
    "status": "running",
    "source": "web",
    "created_at": "2023-09-25T05:55:20.788Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-09-25T05:55:23.481Z",
    "web_url": "https://example.gitlab.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: `: .value` can also be omitted when `key == value` e.g. `{iid, project_id, ref, status, source, created_at, updated_at, web_url}`

Comment: Tip: `[.[] | … ]` can be written `map( … )`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, working in all jq versions:

```
map({
  iid, project_id, ref, status, source,
  created_at, updated_at, web_url
})
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zoJ9zjrNr7f)